# Привести в список списков по исходному DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это делается красиво в стиле Pandas. Пока могу представить только с помощью страшных циклов.
Исходные данные:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
data= {'ID': {0: 308, 1: 308, 2: 309, 3: 309},
 'LON': {0: 37.409936, 1: 37.409936, 2: 37.259936, 3: 37.259936},
 'LAT': {0: 55.967077, 1: 55.967077, 2: 55.997077, 3: 55.997077},
 'PERIOD_TIME': {0: datetime.strptime('2020-02-05 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
  1: datetime.strptime('2020-02-05 01:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
  2: datetime.strptime('2020-02-05 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
  3: datetime.strptime('2020-02-05 01:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')},
 'WEIGHT': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.9, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df получается такого вида:

```
ID  LON LAT PERIOD_TIME WEIGHT
0   308 37.409936   55.967077   2020-02-05 00:00:00 0.1
1   308 37.409936   55.967077   2020-02-05 01:00:00 0.9
2   309 37.259936   55.997077   2020-02-05 00:00:00 0.4
3   309 37.259936   55.997077   2020-02-05 01:00:00 0.5
```

Требуется создать отдельный список из уникальных PERIOD_TIME:

```
['2020-02-05 00:00:00', '2020-02-05 01:00:00']
```

И списки списков из данных [LON, LAT, WEIGHT]:

```
[[[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.1],[37.259936, 55.997077, 0.4]],
[[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.9],[37.259936, 55.997077, 0.5]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
In [50]: res = df.groupby("PERIOD_TIME")["LON","LAT","WEIGHT"].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())

In [51]: res
Out[51]:
PERIOD_TIME
2020-02-05 00:00:00    [[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.1], [37.25...
2020-02-05 01:00:00    [[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.9], [37.25...
dtype: object

In [52]: res.iloc[0]
Out[52]: [[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.1], [37.259936, 55.997077, 0.4]]
```

или так:

```
res = (df
       .assign(PERIOD_TIME=df["PERIOD_TIME"].astype(str))
       .groupby("PERIOD_TIME")
       ["LON","LAT","WEIGHT"]
       .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
       .to_dict())

In [58]: res
Out[58]:
{'2020-02-05 00:00:00': [[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.1],
  [37.259936, 55.997077, 0.4]],
 '2020-02-05 01:00:00': [[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.9],
  [37.259936, 55.997077, 0.5]]}
```

Comment: Здорово. Выглядит как то, что надо. Проблема, что у меня ругается. Возможно потому, что версия 1.0.0.
TypeError: copy() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @Alpensin, хммм..., а где у меня в коде `.copy()` вызывается?

Comment: Не знаю как лучше поделитсья трейсбэком, поэтому скопировал в вопрос.

Comment: нашел багрепорты по этой теме. Похоже порешали. Обновлюсь до  1.0.1 и проверю. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/31456

Comment: @Alpensin, я пока еще на Pandas 0.25.3 сижу...

Comment: обновление до 1.01 помогло. Спасибо, теперь работает отлично и результат как надо.

Answer (score 2):

Для списка из уникальных `PERIOD_TIME`:

```
In[5]: lst = df["PERIOD_TIME"].drop_duplicates().to_list()
In[6]: lst
```

> ```
> Out[6]: [Timestamp('2020-02-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-02-05 01:00:00')]
> ```

```
In[7]: [ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S") for ts in lst]
```

> ```
> Out[7]: ['2020-02-05 00-00-00', '2020-02-05 01-00-00']
> ```

---

Для списка списков из данных `[LON, LAT, WEIGHT]`:

```
In[8]: df1 = df[["LON", "LAT", "WEIGHT"]].T
In[9]: df1
```

> ```
> Out[9]: 
>                 0          1          2          3
> LON     37.409936  37.409936  37.259936  37.259936
> LAT     55.967077  55.967077  55.997077  55.997077
> WEIGHT   0.100000   0.900000   0.400000   0.500000
> ```

```
In[10]: [df1[i].to_list() for i in range(4)]
```

> ```
> Out[10]: 
> [[37.409936, 55.967077, 0.1],
>  [37.409936, 55.967077, 0.9],
>  [37.259936, 55.997077, 0.4],
>  [37.259936, 55.997077, 0.5]]
> ```